# Error getting Microsoft Entra Id (AAD) Token using ADF - 404 : NotFound

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory, bearer-token, powerbi-api

I'm trying to get an AAD token so that I can use in another Web activity to refresh PBI datasets.

However, I'm getting this error when trying to get an AAD Token:.

`Invoking endpoint failed with HttpStatusCode - '404 : NotFound', message - 'The requested endpoint(url) does not exist on the server. Please verify the request server and retry.'`

This is what the Web Activity looks like.

[image]

The URL is:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/@{pipeline().globalParameters.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token'`

The Body is:

```
@concat(
    'grant_type=client_credentials'
    ,'&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    ,'&client_id='
    ,activity('Get SP ClientId').output.value
    ,'&client_secret='
    ,encodeUriComponent(activity('Get SP Secret').output.value)
)
```

I've tried `https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api` for the `Resource` and I still get the same error.

The input for the Web Activity looks like this:

```
{
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token'",
    "body": "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&client_id=<client id>&client_secret=<client secret>"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you check your URL once? It has one extra single quote at the end that you need to remove and replace **resource** with `scope` as you are using v2.0 token endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurred as your URL includes one extra quote and you are using **resource** parameter with `v2.0` token endpoint.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I tried to get access token by passing same values as you:

[image]

To resolve the error, you need to use below **modified** parameters:

**URL**: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

**Method**: POST

**Body:**

```
@concat(
    'grant_type=client_credentials'
    ,'&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    ,'&client_id='
    ,activity('Get SP ClientId').output.value
    ,'&client_secret='
    ,encodeUriComponent(activity('Get SP Secret').output.value)
)
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

> Note that, this token will only work to call **Microsoft Graph API** as the `scope` is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.

To get access token for **Power BI**, you need to change your `scope` value by modifying **Body** like this:

```
@concat(
    'grant_type=client_credentials'
    ,'&scope=https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'
    ,'&client_id='
    ,activity('Get SP ClientId').output.value
    ,'&client_secret='
    ,encodeUriComponent(activity('Get SP Secret').output.value)
)
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

You can now use this access token to make requests to Power BI API.